# Are the lines written on L1 and L2 cache also written in LLC

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu, scheduler

I read "Write hit occurs when the program tries to write on the page which is present in the cache". If a program starts writing in the L1 cache and finds enough lines to write the datas would it also be written in the LLC? I have the doubt because when reading the values brought to the L1 and L2 cache is also brought to the LLC.

Please help me understand. Thank you in advance

Comment: Wow, too much questions in one shot. Good luck with it, but have a chance with [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you. I changed the pattern. I realized it was a bit complicated and also not clear. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this in points, and hopefully if I miss something, someone can add it, or correct my answers:

> Write hit occurs when the program tries to write on the page which is present in the cache

- Indeed, a write hit occurs when the CPU tries to update a data block (also called cache line) that is found in the L1 data cache. However, an updated cache block is updated in the memory hierarchy (i.e. L2, LLC) based on the write back/through scheme your system uses (or other schemes there are).

- Quick note: as far as I know, data in caches are regularly called cache blocks or cache lines, not cache pages.

> If a program starts writing in the L1 cache and finds enough lines to write the datas would it also be written in the LLC?

- This is largely decided by the memory management unit (MMU) and the write back/through scheme. In a multi-core multi-cache system, if a data block is required/processed/updated by several cores at a time, it is very likely that the block is immediately updated in all levels of cache (write through) when it is updated by any of the cores. If each core works separately without data sharing or data sharing is minimal, if a block is updated by a core, it is updated in higher levels of cache only when it is evicted from the L1 cache of the core that updated that block to maintain coherency (write back).

> I have the doubt because when reading the values brought to the L1 and L2 cache is also brought to the LLC.

- If you are working with a multi-core system, it is likely that the process is being handled by multiple cores at a time and therefore any changes introduced to the data by any of the cores necessitates updating the blocks in the entire memory hierarchy to avoid coherency issues.